# replace all \n with <br/>, all which are not inside <textarea> </textarea> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

having a javascript string

```
var s = ' hi there \n <textarea> hello \n there </texarea> hi \n hi';
```

anybody knows how to do a replace of `\n` to `<br/>` that will only affect the `\n` symbols outside of the textarea ?
the result should be this:

```
'hi there <br/> <textarea> hello \n there </texarea> hi <br/> hi';
```

Comment: Obligatory read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What's creating the HTML? Maybe it is easier changing that than post-processing what's broken in the first place…

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli I've seen that, I thought my stuff is different

Comment: The suggestion/link is only not relevant if your code is manipulating data that is known to be both friendly and simple enough. For any code manipulating data given by users it is _not_ enough.

Comment: jQuery's DOM capabilities are most relevant here, not regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a single textarea, you can use `match` to select the textarea. Then, use `replace` using a Regular expression with the global flag to replace all newlines by `<br/>`.

```
var s = s.replace(/\n/g, "<br//>");
//Replace all newline characters by "<br//>"

var textareaContent = s.match(/<textarea>[\s\S]+?<\/textarea>/i);
//Preparation: Selects a textarea

var newString = textareaContent[0].replace(/<br\/\/>/g, "\n");
//Preparation: replaces all "<br//>" inside the textarea by "\n" (newline feed)

s = s.replace(textareaContent[0], newString);
//Replaces the textarea inside the string by the new textarea (= including "\n")

var desiredResult = s.replace(/<br\/\/>/g, "<br/>");
//Replaces the remaining "<br//>" (the ones outside the textarea) by "<br/>"
```

If you have to support multiple textareas, you can use a `for` loop in conjunction with the `exec` method of the Regular expression object.

Comment: How will `/<textarea>[\s\s]+?</textarea>/` match the contents of a text area?

Comment: `\s` matches all white-space characters. `\S` (uppercase) matches all non-white characters. Thus, [\S\s] matches all characters (including newlines, unlike `.`). `[\S\s]+?` means: "match just enough characters so that the next part of the RE can be matched". If you don't use the questionmark, "</textarea>" will be included by `[\s\S]+`.

Comment: Then perhaps there is a typo? Both `\s` appear to be lowercase to me.

Comment: I don't need to replace change the content inside textarea but outside of it

Comment: Read the code carefully. First, ALL `\n` characters are replaced by a temporary `<br//>` character. Then, the `<br//>` characters INSIDE the textarea are reverted to `\n` characters. Finally, the other `<br//>` characters are replaced by `<br/>` characters. Result: All `\n` characters are replaced by `<br/>`, except for the ones inside the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a div and put the \n tags you want in spans. So the first \n would be the first child and the second \n outside the text area would be the last child.

Then you can call the first and last child of the div and manipulate the HTML

```
var s = ' hi there <span class= "changethis">\n</span> <textarea> hello \n there   </texarea> hi <span class= "changethis">\n</span> hi';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line

```
var text = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
```

This will replace all \n characters with 
 tag in text.